# log script to see which parameter opened in url

Tags: php

I want to see parameters or hash part when visitor opens my link like [https://domain.com?Random-parameter=value][1] or [https://domain.com#RandomValue][2]

In general i want to create log script on particular link, that if user opened my link and embed some hashpart in url. how to retrieve that hash part?

Which php **functions** could be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't by using PHP only. You can retrieve the url hash part by using javascript, then send it with ajax, for example. In javascript, the hash part of an url is stored in window.location.hash

To treat it in php, you can use parse_url() :

```
parse_url("http://test?it#nice",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

will return "nice".

Not a solution that I really like, but it's also possible to stock the hash as a cookie, as a workaround. You can see http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/ for more informations.

See ya!